# Basic MySQL Error using UPDATE query

Tags: mysql

I have no idea what I've done wrong, I've tried a lot of different things so far, reworking the statement, etc, but nothing seems to work.

I'm getting this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'SET content='this is content', active='1' WHERE id='1'' at line 1

And this is the query I'm using:

```
UPDATE Pages SET title='$title', SET content='$content', active='$active' 
WHERE id='$id'
```

I've checked to make sure that it's not what's being inserted that is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Delete the second `SET` into your query.

You have:

**SET** title='$title', **SET** content='$content'

Comment: Thank you so much! How on earth did I miss that!